# The call stack contains only external code

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2012

I want that when I click on a  other  became visible. I'm do it using jQuery, but I'm not strong in it. I wrote script:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.visiblePanel').on('click', function () {
                $('.invisiblePanel').toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The layout I have done through С#:

```
Panel visiblePanel = new Panel();
visiblePanel.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
visiblePanel.CssClass = "visiblePanel";
Panel invisiblePanel = new Panel();
invisiblePanel.CssClass = "invisiblePanel";
```

Of course, it didn't work. But also a get an error:
[image]

Without script everything is fine.
I tried to disable Just My Code and got that:

[image] 
Realy, I googled what to do, but without success. Could you help me?

P.S. On jsfiddle.net my script in working.
     http://jsfiddle.net/ZMxg8/

P.P.S: The problem isn't in script! What happened with VS?? What means "The call stack contains only external code"???

Comment: jQuery is running **in the browser**. You have to debug with the script engine. I see that Chrome is launched. Please try again with Internet explorer, and check if you can step your javascript code.

Answer (score 3):

Your code dynamically generates `Panel` but does not include them in the Control tree.

Update your code like this:

```
Panel visiblePanel = new Panel();
visiblePanel.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
visiblePanel.CssClass = "visiblePanel";
this.Controls.Add(visiblePanel);

Panel invisiblePanel = new Panel();
invisiblePanel.CssClass = "invisiblePanel";    
this.Controls.Add(visiblePanel);
```

This should solve the issue.

However, I suggest you to declare this Panels in the aspx markup. This will be easier to maintain.

Comment: I've include those panel, but I just have not showed this part of the code here=)
I have to declare panels dynamically, because their count is not a static

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. Steve B was right. Error "The call stack contains only external code" informed me that the debugger can't debug JavaScript code. And "mscorlib.pdb not loaded" was because when I tried to fix first error, I disabled something in options.=) Thank everybody for helping.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.visiblePanel').click(function () {
            $('.invisiblePanel').toggle();
        });
    });
```

C# Code

```
        Panel visiblePanel = new Panel();
        visiblePanel.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
        visiblePanel.CssClass = "visiblePanel";
        visiblePanel.Width = 10;
        visiblePanel.Height = 10;
        this.Controls.Add(visiblePanel);
        Panel invisiblePanel = new Panel();
        invisiblePanel.Width = 10;
        invisiblePanel.Height = 10;
        invisiblePanel.CssClass = "invisiblePanel";
        invisiblePanel.Style.Add("background-color", "black");            
        this.Controls.Add(invisiblePanel);
```